# What is the different between copula data and pseudo data and when to use them in copula model?

Tags: copula

Copula data is the data in [0,1] with unifrom margins. Also, pseudo data is in [0,1]! In copula packages `copula` and `VineCopula`, we need to transform the data to be pesudo observation even if we generate them using `rCopula`, Why? If I use copula model, then when I can use copula data and when I need to use pseudo data?

Any explanation please? I see that there are the same with very small differences.